# What is difference between await and unawaited in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

What is difference between await and unawaited.

```
AudioPlayer getAudioPlayer() => AudioPlayer();

extension AudioPlayerExtension on AudioPlayer {
  Future<void> replay() async {
    await stop();
    await seek(null);
    unawaited(play());
  }
}
```

Can you explain with this example?

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.1/dart-async/unawaited.html

Answer (score 1):

if you use Await keyword, then the next line won't be executed until this is done!